# add link to leaflet popup in ionic 2 and angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, leaflet

I having to build a mobile app with ionic 2,angular 2 and typescript.
I use leaflet map in my app.
I want to click a marker on map show a popup be contain a link.
this link call a function in typescript file but not work in popup.

```
  public goToMerchant(merchantId) {
    this.navCtrl.push(MerchantPage, { merchantId: merchantId });
  }

 var popupLink='<a (click)="goToMerchant(200)">Show</a>'

 Leaflet.marker([item.lat, item.lng])
        .bindPopup(popupLink)
        .addTo(map);
```

after show popup link not work with click.
how to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is one possible way you can do it:

> Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/CjZrDkxjxvjT5l3qIxMP?p=preview

code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div id="mapid" style="height: 180px;"></div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit{
  name:string = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
  myMap: any;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  goToMerchant(merchantId) {
    //this.navCtrl.push(MerchantPage, { merchantId: merchantId });
    console.log("going to merchant "+merchantId)
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    // setup map
    this.myMap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {}).addTo(this.myMap);

    // note class= merchLink and data-merchId = 200
    var popupLink='<a class="merch-link" data-merchId="200">Show</a>'
    // add marker
    var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09])
        .bindPopup(popupLink)
        .addTo(this.myMap)
        .openPopup();

    // add event listener to newly added a.merch-link element
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".merch-link")
    .addEventListener('click', (e)=>
    {
      // get id from attribute
      var merchId = e.target.getAttribute("data-merchId");
      this.goToMerchant(merchId)
    }));

  }
}
```

Comment: This only works when the popup is created by calling .openPopup(). After the popup is removed it won't work anymore

Comment: you can instead do document.addEventListener('click' ... then filter out event.target, this is the recommended way on mdn

Answer (score 3):

To make this work even when the popup is not opened in the beginning I would suggest a small adaptation to the answer suggested by Ahmed

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div id="mapid" style="height: 180px;"></div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit{
  name:string = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
  myMap: any;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  goToMerchant(merchantId) {
    //this.navCtrl.push(MerchantPage, { merchantId: merchantId });
    console.log("going to merchant "+merchantId)
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    // setup map
    this.myMap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {}).addTo(this.myMap);

    // note class= merchLink and data-merchId = 200
    var popupLink='<a class="merch-link" data-merchId="200">Show</a>'
    // add marker
    var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09])
        .bindPopup(popupLink)
        .addTo(this.myMap);
    let self = this;
    marker.on('popupopen', function() {
      // add event listener to newly added a.merch-link element
      self.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".merch-link")
      .addEventListener('click', (e)=>
      {
        // get id from attribute
        var merchId = e.target.getAttribute("data-merchId");
        self.goToMerchant(merchId)
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much it's working for me ! Could you please explain why i have to use the `let self = this` ?
I tried to change the self to `marker.elementRef` and it's telling that there is no .merch-link.

Comment: That is because 'this' is not in scope of the anonymous 'popupopen' function, because it's a class var, where 'self' is a local function variable that will be referenced to and kept alive in the anonymous function. Quit common in JavaScript.

Comment: I tried this solution but it does not work when you pass from a popup to another without closing the currently opened popup, the link does not work, how can I fix this?